# Move file tabs in PHPStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I want to move a file tab to right or left using only the keyboard, I know that sublime text has such a feature, is this possible in PHPStorm?

Comment: Do you mean -- move editor tabs between editor splits? Or something else?

Comment: No, I know how to move tabs between splits, I have [tab 1], [tab 3], [tab 2] on the same split and I want to move [tab 2] using the keyboard so that the tabs will look like this: [tab 1], [tab 2], [tab 3]

Comment: You already have the answer below then -- such functionality is not currently available. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-23721 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such feature in PhpStorm.

Comment: netbeans has it http://kagda.ru/i/4501126445534_09-11-2017-08:49:02_4501.png
. I'm suprised that phpstorm doesn't have

Comment: There is even a plugin for this, but it doesn't work in 2017.2 unfortunately https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8443-a-move-tab-left-and-right-using-the-keyboard-plugin--by-momomo-com